# Continuity of a similarity on the domain and codomain metric space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I was wondering about the following (self-posed) question:

> If $f\colon (X, d)\to (X, d')$ is a bi-Lipschitz bijection, then, is $f$ continuous on $(X, d)$ (*i.e.*, is $f\colon (X, d)\to (X, d)$ continuous)?

This popped up in an attempt to analyze the following (again, self-posed) question:

> If $f\colon (X, d)\to (X, d')$ is a bi-Lipschitz bijection, then, are the metric topologies on $X$ induced by $d$ and $d'$ the same?

Any insights into any of the above two questions?

---

If you want, I'd be happy to reproduce the path that led me to the former question from the former.

**Partial answer:** I could show that if $f$ is the identity function, then the answer to both the above posed questions are true (the first one being trivial).

Comment: Such maps are usually called bi-Lipschitz. They are homeomorphism.

Comment: You should make it clear that "is $f$ continuous on $(X, d)$?" means "is $f \colon (X, d) \to (X, d)$ continuous?," and not "is $f \colon (X, d) \to (X, d')$" continuous?"

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd be happy to improve the question. Can you provide what seems amiss?

Comment: @ckefa I think that's standard terminology. But I'll still make it explicit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I have got an answer to both of my questions now.

1. *The answer to the first and the second questions are both negative in general:*
   Let $f\colon (X, d)\to (X, d)$ be a discontinuous bijection. Now, we define a metric $d'$ on $X$ by ``transporting'' $d$ so that
   $$
   d'(x, y) := d(f^{-1}(x), f^{-1}(y))\text.
   $$
   Now, $f\colon (X, d)\to (X, d')$ is not just bi-Lipschitz, but also an isometry. Now, if $\mathcal T_d = \mathcal {T_{d'}}$, then the continuity of $f\colon (X, d)\to (X, d')$ would have implied the continuity of $f\colon (X, d)\to (X, d)$ (continuity being a topological property). Hence $\mathcal T_d \ne \mathcal T_{d'}$ even when $(X, d)$ and $(X, d')$ are isometric.
2. *However, if $f$ is the identity function, then answer to the both the questions are affirmative:*
   The first question is trivially true. For the second question, consider a ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ in $(X, d)$. We show that it is open in $\mathcal T_{d'}$. Let $y\in B_\epsilon(x)$ and let $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(y)\subseteq B_\epsilon(x)$ (we could take $\delta$ to be, for instance, $\epsilon - d(x, y)$). Now, we find a $\delta' > 0$ such that the ball $B'_{\delta'}(y)$ in $(X, d')$ is contained in $B_\delta(y)$. We can simply take $\delta < \epsilon c$ where $c$ is the "left Lipschitz constant": $c d(x, y) \le d'(x, y)$.

Comment: @ckefa Read it carefully: I am *asserting* that $\mathcal T_d \ne \mathcal T_{d'}$.